# jQuery: Count Number of Inputs with a Specific Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to count the number of text inputs with a value of 1.

I have tried the following but with no luck.

```
$('.class[value="1"]').length
$('.class:contains("1")').length
```

Using `$('.class[value="1"]')` technically works, however, if the values in the text input are changed after load, it still counts it as its default load value.

I took a long shot by using the `.live` click event to get the current value but still no luck.

I had no luck at all using `$('.class:contains("1")')`

It seems very simple, but has so far eluded me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This example demonstrates that this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    alert($(":input[value='1']").length);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="How many?">
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you can just loop:

```
var matches = 0;
$(":input.class").each(function(i, val) {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    matches++;
  }
});
```

Comment: I thought JQuery may have a shorthand one liner, however, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need to iterate with $.each() if you want current val() values:

```
k=0;
$('.class').each(function(i, e) {
  if ($(e).val() == "1") k++;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(':input.class').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == '1'
})
```